# Leaving MacBook Air on sleep for more than 5 hours causes it to not wake up at all

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I am facing an issue with my brand new MacBook Air 2019 Retina True Tone model

When I put my Mac to sleep, close off the lid and let it stay like this overnight (roughly for about 6-7 hours), when I open the lid again, my Mac doesn't starts automatically. Even when I press the trackpad, spacebar etc, it doesn't wake up. I have to press the power button to turn it back on.

However, during the day, in my breaktime I leave it on sleep mode and close the lid for about 1-2 hours, opening the lid wakes up the MacBook normally.

This machine is working just fine for me except for when I wake up every morning and see that I can't start my work from where I left because my MacBook doesn't comes out of sleep.I have to shut down using the power button and then turn on my Mac.

Can someone tell me a concrete solution to this? Because I can't test each solution separately because it would consume too many days since the only time I can leave my Mac on sleep for about 5-6 hours is when I sleep.

Note : Yesterday I had updated my OS to Catalina as per the recommendation of apple chat executive, but the same problem happened today morning aswell and right now my software is up to date.

Comment: what settings do you have in Energy Saver?

Comment: @dwightk they are all on default, as it came out of the box

Comment: Should I suggest SMC reset? I mean it includes "Your Mac notebook doesn't respond properly when you close or open the lid." https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: @ankii in my case it happens only when I leave it on sleep for about 5+ hours, do you think I should follow the steps given in link?

Comment: It is seen as a troubleshoot step.. so yes I think.